# How to set root view controller in Today extension programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

I have a project without storyboard. I've set root view controller in `AppDelegate`. Now I've added a today extension. I got a new storyboard `MainInterface.storyboard` with root view controller `TodayViewController`. How can I delete `MainInterface.storyboard` and set root view controller programmatically?

Comment: Try to remove MainInterface.storyboard from Deployment Info in your app General settings.

Comment: @Milan If I remove it, I will get blank screen. Isn't?

Comment: I guess you won't coz you are setting your window's rootViewController in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: @Milan Today Extension doesn't have AppDelegate. Please check https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/today-extension-ios-tutorial-ios11

Answer (score 2):

**Xcode 11.0**

Open **Info.plist** from your Extension and change

```
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    ...
</dict>
```

to:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NameOfYourExtension.NameOfYourViewController</string>
    ...
</dict>
```

Delete **MainInterface.storyboard** and it should work without any faults.

Answer (score 0):

Using the URL Scheme to achieve your goal, See this code.

Write the following code in **TodayViewController** (Today extension swift file)

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let url = URL(string: "MyAppTodayExtension://")!
        self.extensionContext?.open(url, completionHandler: { (success) in
            if (!success) {
                print("error: failed to open app from Today Extension")
            }
        })
    }
```

Add URL Scheme in your **info.plist** file

[image]

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>MyAppTodayExtension</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

When you tap in today extension then get call following method in **AppDelegate.swift** file.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        //Write code here for navigating to a specific controller OR set root view controller
        return true
    }
```